# How to get the elements in a select tag after clicking something with beautiful soup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Trying to scrap this website: https://fbref.com/en/

And It tells you to select a league then a team I want to select a league somehow then afterwards scrap the teams option from the website after I select a league. How do I do that?

My code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

result=requests.get('https://fbref.com/en/')
soup=BeautifulSoup(result.text, 'html.parser')

leagues=[]
teams=[]

for option in soup.find('select', id='league_choice'):

      leagues.append(option.text)

for option in soup.find('select', id='team_choice'):

    teams.append(option.text)
```

I know selenium might work for this, but I was wondering if there was a way to do it with beautiful soup.

Answer (score 0):

You need Selenium to interact with the website, Beautiful Soup can only parse (analyse/read) the html code of the page.

So to solve your problem you need to select each league and then get the team.

Here is a relevant documentation : https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/support_features/select_lists/